# Perforce revert operation gives client unknown. Create it with p4 client command

Tags: perforce

I have already created a perforce client with command:

```
p4 client -o -e <my_clientname>
```

and it gave a message  created with the required user.

but while using this clientname for revert operation with command

```
p4 -c <my_clientname> revert <perforce_path...>
```

it gives me an error `"Client <my_clientname> unknown - use 'client'` command to create it."

**Additional Info:** I am working on a jenkins setup with Perforce plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p4 client -o` does **not** create your client; it simply prints out to stdout the form specification that you *could* have used to create your client.

To create your client, do:

```
`p4 client -o <my-client-name> | p4 client -i`
```

By the way, in your question, you wrote that you also passed the `-e` flag. I don't believe there is a `-e` flag to `p4 client`.

Comment: Also, `revert` won't do anything if you haven't opened any files.  :)

Comment: I obviously have shelved some files Sam. :)

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton That "e" got printed here by mistake. But your solution worked for me in creating workspace. Thanks for that. But now while calling revert using perforce changelist with this command
p4 -c <my_client_name> unshelve -f -s %SHELVED_CL% <path_of_perforce_file_to_be_unshelved>...
I get an error: "file(s) not opened on this client"
Although I checked my workspace mapping using 
p4 -p <host_name> client <my_client_name>
and it was correct.

Comment: Shelved files aren't the same as opened files.  Maybe you want to do "shelve -d"?  You might save some time by just saying in your question what your plugin is supposed to accomplish; it might not be something that requires a workspace at all!

Comment: I found that my user was not given permission to edit the files. I checked that using p4 protects. So, now its working after giving the required permission.